# hamburger menu covers logo

Tags: html, css

My hamburger menu blocks part of the logo on smaller screen sizes, and I'm not sure how to fix it so that the logo appears in front of the menu before the menu is clicked. [This is what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByOF5.png)

I tried setting the background of the *label .menu* to transparent but the logo appears after the menu is clicked. [I'm talking about this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7mxa.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I know my code's messy. I'll fix it later, so don't judge the messy code, please.

```css
.logo {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: -15px;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}

.midnight-logo {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

label .hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  background: #C8C8C8;
}

label .hamburger:after,
label .hamburger:before {
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #C8C8C8;
}

label .hamburger:before {
  top: -10px;
}

label .hamburger:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

label input {
  display: none;
}

label input:checked+.menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #000, 0 0 0 100vh #000;
  border-radius: 0;
}

label input:checked+.menu .hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

label input:checked+.menu .hamburger:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

label input:checked+.menu .hamburger:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
}

label input:checked+.menu+ul {
  display: block;
}

label .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 155px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #000, 0 0 0 0 #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000;
}

label ul {
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
  transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
}

label a {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<img class="logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/xsQHR3Y/midnight-logo.png">

<label>

                <input type="checkbox">

                <span class="menu"> 
    
                <span class="hamburger"> </span> </span>

                    <ul> 
        
                        <li> <a href="home.html"> Home </a> </li> 
        
                        <li> <a href="about.html"> About </a> </li>
        
                        <li> <a href="contact.html"> Contact </a> </li>

                    </ul>

            </label>
```

Comment: I can't see the logo so I can't tell what you mean. Can you include the full image URL in your snippet?

Comment: @Bman70 My apologies. I've included the logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these edits to the `.logo` class in CSS:

`z-index: 3;
 pointer-events: none;`

This will make the logo start out above the menu. The pointer-events styling lets the menu stay clickable even though it's under the logo. However, it will stay on top after the menu is clicked.

If you don't want it to stay on top, add some Javascript onclick event to the menu. So that the logo reverts to a lower `z-index` when the menu is clicked. Something like `<span class="menu" onclick="logoBack()">`.

Then put some Javascript between `<script></script>` tags. I used the code below in the snippet. Hope this helps!

```js
function logoBack() {
var logo = document.getElementsByClassName('logo')[0];
logo.style.zIndex = "0";
};
```

```css
.logo {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: -15px;
  height: auto;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  z-index: 3;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.midnight-logo {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}

label .hamburger {
  position: fixed;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 2px;
  display: block;
  transform-origin: center;
  -webkit-transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  background: #C8C8C8;
}

label .hamburger:after,
label .hamburger:before {
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #C8C8C8;
}

label .hamburger:before {
  top: -10px;
}

label .hamburger:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

label input {
  display: none;
}

label input:checked+.menu {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 100vw #000, 0 0 0 100vh #000;
  border-radius: 0;
}

label input:checked+.menu .hamburger {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

label input:checked+.menu .hamburger:after {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

label input:checked+.menu .hamburger:before {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  top: 0;
}

label input:checked+.menu+ul {
  display: block;
}


label .menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: -100px;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100px;
  height: 155px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 #000, 0 0 0 0 #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #000;

}

label ul {
  z-index: 200;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: none;
  transition: .25s 0s ease-in-out;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
}

label a {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! HTML>
<head>
</head>

<body> 
<img class="logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/xsQHR3Y/midnight-logo.png">

<label>
                <input type="checkbox">

                <span class="menu" onclick="logoBack()"> 
    
                <span class="hamburger"> </span> </span>

                    <ul> 
        
                        <li> <a href="home.html"> Home </a> </li> 
        
                        <li> <a href="about.html"> About </a> </li>
        
                        <li> <a href="contact.html"> Contact </a> </li>

                    </ul>

            </label>
            
            </body>

            </html>
```